# Get image asset relative url

Tags: assets, url, plugin-blitz

I'm using image transforms and `getUrl()` method to display an image.

I'm using Blitz to export my site as a static website.

My problem is that .html pages get cached with images that have full urls like this: `http://localhost:8888/assets/pages/_medium/image.jpg`

There must be an obvious solution that i'm missing... I've tried getPath but it doesn't support image transforms. Removing `http://localhost:8888` should do the job.. but how?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the settings of your asset's volume:

Go to: Settings > Assets > [Your Volume Name here]

Check the field "Base URL". If it starts with the alias `@web`, remove it.

E.g. "`@web/images`" -> "`/images`".

Now check the URL of your image again.